# Using bump maps in with the stencil brush in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, normal-map

I am fairly new to blender. I have just finished UV unwrapping and coloring my model, and I am ready to texture it. When I load a bump map into a texture slot and start painting on the model there are no bumps, just color. What I am trying to do is at around 11 minutes 50 seconds in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqokgANRb0M. I would like to do it in cycles.  Is this possible? I have tried many node setups with varying UV images and other things. Is there a certain node setup I need to make? I have a greyscale and normal map of the image, if this would make a difference.

[image: this is the node setup and modifier stack. I have images of the model if needed,]

Answer (score 1):

I use a bump node to plug the image into, and then route it to the Normal of the shaders like the image I have here[image: bump]